# Symfony2 form builder constraints don't work in collection of forms

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints, formbuilder

I want to embed a Collection of Forms. That works fine! But the problem is, that the validation of a non mapped field ist not working. The code:

**UserType.php**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType 
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('contactPersons', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ContactPersonCreateType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
        ))
        ...
    }
```

**ContactPersonCreateType.php**

```
class ContactPersonCreateType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('kind', 'text', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
                new Length(array('min' => 3)),
            )
        ))
        ...
    }
```

I don't know why, but it will not be validated!
Can somebody help?

Comment: add 'cascade_validation' => true, in contactPersons field.

Comment: sry, that was a mistake in the question. I have already done it. I also tried to add 'cascade_validation' => true in the OptionsResolver. Nothing works!